# As-pattern "contrivedMap" example not working

Tags: haskell

[Haskell Wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Pattern_matching) defines this function:

```
contrivedMap :: ([a] -> a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
contrivedMap f [] = []
contrivedMap f list@(x:xs) = f list x : contrivedMap f xs
```

I am getting an error when I try to use it:

```
> contrivedMap (*2) [1,2,3]

<interactive>:4:15: error:
• Couldn't match type ‘[a0]’ with ‘a0 -> b’
  Expected type: [a0] -> a0 -> b
    Actual type: (a0 -> b) -> a0 -> b
• In the first argument of ‘contrivedMap’, namely ‘(* 2)’
  In the expression: contrivedMap (* 2) [1, 2, 3]
  In an equation for ‘it’: it = contrivedMap (* 2) [1, 2, 3]
• Relevant bindings include it :: [b] (bound at <interactive>:4:1)
```

I see that the types don't match:

```
> :t (*2) 
(*2) :: Num a => a -> a

> :t contrivedMap
contrivedMap :: ([a] -> a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

But how do I fix it?

Comment: By choosing a function that matches.

Comment: For example `\x -> (*2)`, or equivalently `const (*2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I see they don't match, but how do I fix it?

You can fix it by proper usage of this function.

You've defined a function `mapEx` which iterates over the elements of a list and applies the provided function on **every element**, i. e. you need to provide a function, that takes an element of a list and returns a result. For example `(*2)` - takes a `Num` and returns a doubled value.

Expectedly:

`mapEx (*2) [1,2,3]` evaluates as `[2, 4, 6]`

But the `contrivedMap` function is slightly different. It also iterates over the elements of a list, but the provided function takes **2** arguments **the list of elements from the iterated element to the end** and **the iterated element**

`contrivedMap f [1,2,3]` is going to contain:

```
[(f [1,2,3] 1), (f [2,3] 2), (f [3] 3)]
```

Thus, you'll want to provide the function, which works correctly with these arguments, i. e. has the type `([a] -> a -> b)`. For example, `f list x = (sum list) * x` or just `f = (*) . sum`

`contrivedMap ((*) . sum) [1,2,3]` returns `[6,10,9]`, which is:

```
[(sum [1,2,3]) * 1, (sum [2,3]) * 2, (sum [3]) * 3]
```

Comment: So, in words, my understanding is now: When one sees ([a] -> a -> b) it means that contrivedMap requires one function that takes a list of type a's, and returns a single value of type a, and then takes that a and returns a single value of type b,  meaning it may or may not be of type a.  The composition ((*) .sum) operating on [1,23] does exactly that.  I must say that I will be studying your reply for some time as I think it is the key to understanding Haskell syntax.  Much appreciated.

Comment: No, `[a] -> a -> b` means that it takes *two* arguments, an `[a]` and an `a`, and returns a `b`. To be pedantic, it actually takes a `[a]` and returns a function that takes an `a` and returns a `b`.